# android : how does the OS chose a component implementation when multiple implementation respond to the same intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a free and a premium version of the same app (almost same code, same classes with "if"s here and there, different packages in the manifest, same process name in the manifest). The main activity calls a service to execute some stuff, using an IMPLICIT intent.

When I install both apps on the phone, it turns out that the premium activity actually starts a "free" service sometimes and a "premium" service another.
I have been playing around with categories and the packagemanager but it seems too complicated.

Questions :

1. how does Android handle multiple components responding to a same Intent?
2. how would you do what I am trying to do: I have the same service in multiple apps and I only want one instance being called from all the apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could add an extra boolean *isPremium* to the intent. Naturally you will need some more of those "if's".

Activity:

```
//send broadcast
Intent serviceStarted = new Intent(Actions.ACTION_START_SERVICE);
serviceStarted.putExtra(Extras.EXTRA_PREMIUM_VERSION, PREMIUM_VERSION);
sendBroadcast(serviceStarted);
```

Receiver:

```
if (!intent.getExtras().getBoolean(Extras.EXTRA_PREMIUM_VERSION)) {
    Log.v(TAG, " - ignoring wrong version");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I believe Android only forwards that intent to a single receiver so if it's not the right one, the other one will never receive it. I have noticed that a popup is displayed if multiple activities respond to the same intent but I wonder about services.

Comment: I depends on how you call it - startActivity and startService is aimed att single Activity/Service and may trigger popup to select what to start. But using sendBroadcast will trigger all receivers given the receiver pass it on.